# how to select stuff in java

Tags: java, selection

this is just an example but pretend that I have a class I have the scanner method and I want this code to make a person select the soldier they want for example if they chose soldier it would display the health and hit points of soldier , while if they entered soldier2 it would display the health and the hit points of soldier2, but I do not want to use if and else statement it takes to long

```
public class Attack {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        troops soldier = new troops(150,(int)(Math.random() * 35) + 25);
        troops soldier2 = new troops(150,(int)(Math.random() * 35) + 25);
        System.out.println("please select the troop you want to select");
    }
}
```

Comment: You could create an array and ask the user for the number of the troop which you use as an index to the array.

Comment: would that still work if they all had different name such as: soldier 2 and the other would be called tank hunter or something else

Comment: An array is a single variable, so you will only have one variable name.

Comment: If you want the user to type in a "name" instead of a number, consider using `Map<String, Troops>` instead.